# DateTime Symfony first month is December

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

input:

> (new \DateTime('2017-01 midnight last day'))->format('Y-m-d')

output:

> 2016-12-31

Shouldn't it be 2017-01-31 ?

It might work like 2017 substract 1 month..

Comment: for
(new \DateTime('2017-02 midnight last day'))->format('Y-m-d')
i get
2017-01-31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you takes '2017-01', it means '2017-01-01'

`echo new \DateTime('2017-01 midnight'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');//2017-01-01 00:00:00`

and the 'last day' is means '-1 day' in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)'s changelog:

> PHP5.3.3  "first day" and "last day" changed to behave has "+1 day" and "-1 day", respectively. Previously, the behaviour was as "first day of" and "last day of".

Comment: new \DateTime('last day of 2017-01 midnight') is what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can also get last date of month like this:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime('2017-01');
$dateTime->format('Y-m-t');  //output : "2017-01-31"
```

if you only want, last date:

```
$dateTime->format('t'); //output : "31"
```

Or, In a single line :

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2017-01-01")->format("Y-m-t");
```

Or, just use :

```
date("Y-m-t", strtotime("2017-01-31"))
```